# sort a list numerically and alphabetically

Tags: sort

I'm trying to find most common word sorted alphabetically. 
For example:

```
  2 went
  2 wonder
  2 wont
  3 began
  3 little
  3 moment
  3 rabbit
  3 thing
  3 till
  4 alice
  4 bottle
  4 came
  4 sure
  4 window
```

The output should be `alice` (has highest value and it is the first word alphabetically).

I'm doing `sort -nr` and can't figure out what to do next.

Comment: Is that your source data, or the desired output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To sort by two fields, you need to tell sort what they are, and how to sort them; for example:

```
sort -k1,1nr -k2b < input
```

sorts by field 1 (`-k1,1`) numerically in reverse (descending) order; for lines where field 1 is equal, secondarily sort by the rest of the line (`-k2`) normally (lexically) not including the leading blanks (the spacing between the first and second field) in the sort key (`b`).  The output on your sample input is:

```
  4 alice
  4 bottle
  4 came
  4 sure
  4 window
  3 began
  3 little
  3 moment
  3 rabbit
  3 thing
  3 till
  2 went
  2 wonder
  2 wont
```

Answer (score 0):

Though Jeff already answered your question using only `sort`, I thought I'd post my approach anyway. I didn't know about `sort`'s ability to sort by two fields, so I used it merely for "pre"-sorting you input. Since the words are ordered Z-A in every section, we just need to reverse their order. For this, I'm using `awk`:

```
sort -r file | awk '{if($1==x){var=$0"\n"var} else{print var;var=$0;x=$1}} END{print var}' | grep -v ^$
```

The `grep -v ^$` is only there to remove the first line of `awk`'s output, which is empty.